# Need to index sub-lists after pandas.explode()

Tags: python, pandas

I need to keep track of list positions of the items that are created after `pd.explode()`. While I can do this with few lines of code, like in `iterrows()`, I am trying to find fast Pandas way to do this.

before explode

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'foo':[['a','b','c'],['d'],['e', 'f']]})

         foo
0  [a, b, c]
1        [d]
2     [e, f]
```

after explode

```
df = df.explode('foo', ignore_index=True)
df['idx'] = [0,1,2,0,0,1]  # NEED TO REPLACE THIS LINE WITH SMART PANDAS FUNCTION

  foo  idx
0   a    0
1   b    1
2   c    2
3   d    0
4   e    0
5   f    1
```

The desired state includes `idx` column with indices of the original lists. How to create it properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First remove `ignore_index=True` from `explode` for repeated index values, so possible use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) by `index` an last create default index:

```
df = df.explode('foo')

df['idx'] = df.groupby(level=0).cumcount()
#alternative
#df['idx'] = df.groupby(df.index).cumcount()
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
  foo  idx
0   a    0
1   b    1
2   c    2
3   d    0
4   e    0
5   f    1
```

Another idea is flatten `range`s by lengths of lists:

```
L = [y for x in df['foo'] for y in range(len(x))]
df = df.explode('foo', ignore_index=True)
df['idx'] = L

print (df)
  foo  idx
0   a    0
1   b    1
2   c    2
3   d    0
4   e    0
5   f    1
```

Comment: Is there a preference of using `df.groupby(level=0)` over `df.groupby(df.index)`? Which is better? Or both are same?

Comment: @MayankPorwal - I think `level=0` is more preferable, I think because more flexible if need working with MultiIndex (and selcting first or second level)

Comment: Nice trick with `cumcount`! Thanks, @jezrael! you totally dominate pandas space here.